# GD text size not changing

Tags: php, gd

I wrote code for adding text into an image with GD ; and it does work but size is not changing for no reason.

Here is my code:

```
$image = imagecreatefromjpeg(path);

$text_number = '5101';

$font_size = 20;

$font_color = imagecolorallocate($image,255,255,255);

imagestring($image,$font_size,380,240,$text_number,$font_color);

imagejpeg($image,path to save , 100);
```

I tried to change `$font_size`, its not working

nothing work

thanks .

Comment: Maybe you want to use [`imagefttext()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagefttext.php) instead? You can specify font size with that.

Comment: please be more specific than its not working. like what is not working what's the current behavior etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think 20 is to large to be an argument of imagestring.

It defined as

```
bool imagestring ( resource $image , int $font , int $x , int $y , string $string , int $color )
```

$font has a maximum value of 5, as long You didn't load own fonts.

http://php.net/manual/de/function.imagestring.php